# Export html table to excel with date set as text

Tags: javascript, excel, html-table

Good day, I'm having problem with my downloadable excel. I am using `table2excel.js` and it's working fine but my problem is the `date` in date column, it should be set as text. I already formatted the date and convert it to string using my javascript but the downloaded excel always shows it as date not a text. My date format in html table is `04-29-2021` but the result in excel is different. How can I convert it to text? Thanks in advance

> javascript

```
$scope.formatDate1 = function (dates) {
        var monthNames = [
            "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December"
        ];
        dates = dates.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, '')
        var date = new Date(parseInt(dates));
        //console.log(date);
        var day = date.getDate();
        var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
        var m = ''
        var d = ''
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        if (monthIndex < 10) {
            m = '0' + (monthIndex + 1)
        } else {
            m = (monthIndex + 1)
        }
        if (day < 10) {
            d = '0' + day
        } else {
            d = day
        }
        return m + '-' + d + '-' + year;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the github page answers your question: https://github.com/rusty1s/table2excel#cell-type-handlers

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an equals-apostrophe `='` at the beginning of the date to let excel know that it is a text cell?

```
return "='" + m + '-' + d + '-' + year;
```

Comment: but the apostrophe will be displayed in the downloaded excel file sir

Comment: I already tried it sir. The apostrophe was shown after the date. By the way sir i'm downloading `xls` file sir

Comment: I updated my answer, please add `=` before apostrophe @pryxen

Comment: it doesn't work in `xls` format sir. I tried it and the equal sign and apostrophe was displayed too